# RTP, Media packets behind firewall and behind Nat makes life hard to fix it, now i am trying to do the UDP hole punching, to get ride of it

Tags: java, security, networking, centos, fedora

I am trying to make a peer 2 peer audio/video application, but behind NAT and behind firewall causing my application failture, i figure out that Skype does it and other application does also other approach, then i decided to use this approach which will allow my application to work behind NAT office/home.

**UDP Hole punching:**

So far, tried hping2 and netcat. Server, pc1 behind nat/firewall and pc2 behind nat/firewall

```
local/1$ nc -u 14141 -l  # ME, step 1
remoteServer$ echo "hello" | nc -p 53 -u xx.23.xx.xx 14141  # My server, to say hello 
nc: Write error: No route to host    
local/2$ hping2 -c 1 -2 -s 14141 -p 53 xx.21.xx.xx # Me from second terminal making a hole
remoteServer$ echo "hello" | nc -p 53 -u xx.23.xx.xx 14141 # My server again say hell
local/1 $ nc -u 14141 -l # ME, step 1 was running and it received "hello" now
 hello
```

But local/1 how to get the hello, without hping2 or what is exactly hping2? 
Can anyone suggest? Or how i can just do the A (local) B(server) C(my friend) communicate with peer 2 peer using this method?

Useful links:
http://www.masquerade.cz/en/nat-tunel-metodou-udp-hole-punching-v-jazyce-java/

**Follow up:**
UPnP is best solution? But it looks for the very next hop, so in that case it will fail for this road map (if i am not wrong):

Me (behind NAT) **->** *MyOffice (with router, 50 laptops)* **->** ISP1 **->** ISP2 **->** FriendOffice (router, 90 laptops) **->** Friend (behind NAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What many p2p applications do is to connect to the nearest router and ask them to open a port to themselves. Read about UPnP and NAT-PMP protocols.

Comment: @road to yamburg: For java is this better http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnat-pmplib/files/   But i need 4 public port audio in/out video in/out chat full duplex and file transfer another port. Almost public port 6 ports. Also some case, it looks like ISP NAT issues, does UPnP or NAT-PMP works with ISP level or its only in the Office main router level access?

Comment: @road to yamburg: UPnP will only reach to Myoffice point (if you mean thats next-hop router), but in that case, ISP is blocking still my ports, so none can still contact my ports yet with UPnP solution? Assume this network example: Me (behind NAT) -> MyOffice (with router, 50 laptops) -> ISP1 -> ISP2 -> FriendOffice (router, 90 laptops) -> Friend (behind NAT)

Comment: @road to yamburg: If you see above my example of UDP hole punching. That really solves my far far end issues. What do you think about that method instead of UPnP? Because with UPnP i believe we will end up in the nearest next hop. And it will not reach all other participants involved. But a UDP hole punching guarantee it will do, above example is an working sample, i tested it worked.

Comment: Hole punching, if I understand what you did, is more generic. Keep in mind though that IPv4 address space was officially exhausted this Feb. This Jun(?) the world will face the IPv6 day, where giant companies will try and push for IPv6. If something you develop is to be released a year or so in future, you may think of focus on IPv6 instead of all this fiddling with NATs. ;)

Comment: @road to yamburg: you included a nice point here. I was not caring about that. Do you for that reason also recommending UPnP or NAT-PMP?